# Symfony doctrine:mapping:import doesn't import the reflective associations tables

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a MySQL database, where I have a few tables. Two of them are reflective association table, the association table R-asso reference two lines of a table A. The association table contains additional data, such as a date, a string.

```
     +---------------+
     |               |  0..*
     |               |
+----+----+      +---v-----+
| R-asso  |      |    A    |
+---------+      +---------+
| date    |      | attr    +-------(other entities)
| String  |      |         |
|         |      |         |
|         |      |         |
+---^-----+      +---+-----+
    |                |
    |                | 0..*
    |                |
    +----------------+
```

When I import my entities in symfony, the R-asso entity is not generated. Instead, I have a ManyToMany association between my A's objects, but I lost the information contained in my association!

I tried to import again my entities, I checked my associations in my database, I search in which case Symfony doesn't generate an entity but I found nothing.

I want for Symfony to generate my R-asso entity, and associate it with my object A, instead of create a ManyToMany association between A objects.